# Moved Custom Report from development to production in CRM

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, reporting-services

I moved a custom built report in CRM development instance to production but encountered an error while running it.

The CRM development instance is on a server. I have a SQL Server where I created my reports (BIDS). I copied the .RDL file from the SQL Server to my local drive. I uploaded the report to Production but I encountered the following error:

> Report cannot be displayed (rsProcessingAborted), Invalid Argument.

Some additional information:

- Data Source: Microsoft SQL Server(SQL Client)
- Server Name: "My server name"
- Windows Authentication
- Database: "My Database"

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: You need to find some more information to help resolve this - check the Reporting Services log file as there should be more information on the error there. Are you able to run other custom CRM reports that have been deployed to production?

Comment: The issue was with connection string and security permissions. Looking into them now. But I think I am headed in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue for you, try the advice here:

http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/reporting-error-report-cannot-be-displayed-rsprocessingaborted/comment-page-1/

It fixed the problem for me.